# How to prepare data to edit with CKeditor

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I have a form with a textarea, the textarea is replaced with the wysiwyg editor, CKeditor

It works great and I can add the data to the database using `htmlentities` and that works great, I can retrieve the data and display it with php, that works great...

But if I try to load it back into the CKeditor for editing purposes, the images are broken and the sources are replaced with backslashes

What do I need to do in order to prepare the content for ckeditor to use it and display it accuratly?

Any help is appreciated

Right now here is the code...

```
<textarea name="article" id="textarea">
    <?php if (isset($record['article'])) { echo $record['article']; } ?>
</textarea>
```

and the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea', {
    toolbar: [
        ['Maximize'],
        ['Image','oembed'],
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteFromWord'],
        ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace'],
        ['Link','Unlink'],
        ['Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar'],
        ['Bold','Italic','StrikeThrough'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],
        ['Format', 'FontSize', 'Subscript','Superscript', 'NumberedList','BulletedList','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
        ['ShowBlocks', 'RemoveFormat', 'Source']
    ],
    width: '99%',
    height: 400,
    defaultLanguage: 'en',
    language: 'en'
});
});
```

Comment: dont use htmlentities when adding the date to the db, that's the problem

Comment: Thanks Dagon but it does not seem to make a difference either way

Answer (score 0):

Turns out with the help of Dagon's comment and a little exploration it was pretty simple, I removed the htmlentities when updating the database and replaced this code...

```
<textarea name="article" id="textarea">
    <?php if (isset($record['article'])) { echo $record['article']; } ?>
</textarea>
```

With this...

```
<textarea name="article" id="textarea">
    <?php if (isset($record['article'])) { echo stripslashes($record['article']); } ?>
</textarea>
```